# Script without debbuger won't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, payment-gateway

Currently I'm facing very strange issue.
What I'm doing is to integrate payment gateway in my code (**CyberSource PaymentGateway**). 
First I call Ajax and do some operation and after that I get json result with parameters and fill all required parameters with json result and do submit form.
Problem is when I do submit form Payment Gateway won't work and gives

> 403 - Unauthorized

but if I put **debugger** to check the script, all working fine.
Following is my code. Please check and let me know if I'm missing something.

**PaymentForm**

```
<form id='payment_confirmation' method='post' style="display:none">
    <input type='hidden' name='access_key' id='access_key' />
    <input type='hidden' name='profile_id' id='profile_id' />
    <input type='hidden' name='transaction_uuid' id='transaction_uuid' />
    <input type='hidden' name='signed_field_names' id='signed_field_names' value='access_key,profile_id,transaction_uuid,signed_field_names,unsigned_field_names,signed_date_time,locale,transaction_type,reference_number,amount,currency,payment_method,bill_to_forename,bill_to_surname,bill_to_email,bill_to_phone,bill_to_address_line1,bill_to_address_city,bill_to_address_state,bill_to_address_country,bill_to_address_postal_code,ignore_cvn' />
    <input type='hidden' name='unsigned_field_names' id='unsigned_field_names' value='card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date,card_cvn' />
    <input type='hidden' name='signed_date_time' id='signed_date_time' />
    <input type='hidden' name='locale' id='locale' value='en' />
    <input type='hidden' name='ignore_cvn' id='ignore_cvn' value='false' />
    <input type='hidden' name='card_cvn' id='card_cvn' />
    <fieldset>
        <div id='paymentDetailsSection' class='section'>
            <input type='hidden' id='transaction_type' name='transaction_type' size='25' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='reference_number' name='reference_number' size='25' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='amount' name='amount' size='25' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='currency' name='currency' size='25' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='payment_method' name='payment_method' value='card' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_forename' name='bill_to_forename' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_surname' name='bill_to_surname' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_email' name='bill_to_email' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_phone' name='bill_to_phone' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_address_line1' name='bill_to_address_line1' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_address_city' name='bill_to_address_city' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_address_state' name='bill_to_address_state' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_address_country' name='bill_to_address_country' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='bill_to_address_postal_code' name='bill_to_address_postal_code' /><br />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div id='UnsignedDataSection' class='section'>
            <input type='hidden' id='card_type' name='card_type' value='001' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='card_number' name='card_number' /><br />
            <input type='hidden' id='card_expiry_date' name='card_expiry_date' /><br />
        </div>
        <input type='hidden' id='signature' name='signature' />
    </fieldset>
    <input type='submit' id='btnsubmit' value='Confirm' />
</form>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        data: JSON.stringify(<PARAMS>),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: OnError
    });
    function OnSuccessPNRSummary(response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
        debugger //<- IF I REMOVE THIS OR NOT IN DEBUGGING, CODE IS NOT WORKING
        $('#payment_confirmation').attr("action", data.url);
        $('#access_key').val(data.access_key);
        $('#profile_id').val(data.profile_id);
        $('#transaction_uuid').val(data.transaction_uuid);
        $('#signed_date_time').val(data.signed_date_time);
        $('#card_cvn').val(data.card_cvn);
        $('#transaction_type').val(data.transaction_type);
        $('#reference_number').val(data.reference_number);
        $('#amount').val(data.amount);
        $('#currency').val(data.currency);
        $('#bill_to_forename').val(data.bill_to_forename);
        $('#bill_to_surname').val(data.bill_to_surname);
        $('#bill_to_email').val(data.bill_to_email);
        $('#bill_to_phone').val(data.bill_to_phone);
        $('#bill_to_address_line1').val(data.bill_to_address_line1);
        $('#bill_to_address_city').val(data.bill_to_address_city);
        $('#bill_to_address_state').val(data.bill_to_address_state);
        $('#bill_to_address_country').val(data.bill_to_address_country);
        $('#bill_to_address_postal_code').val(data.bill_to_address_postal_code);
        $('#card_number').val(data.card_number);
        $('#card_expiry_date').val(data.card_expiry_date);
        $('#signature').val(data.sign);
        //$("#payment_confirmation").submit(); <-- same problem
        $("#btnsubmit").click()
    }
```

Comment: Well i am not sure about the perfect solution here..but my guess is you need a setTimeout in your JS. The thing is your code only works while using debugger because while using debugger your whole page loaded already. The same you can achieve using setTimeout. Its a guess though but should work.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Thanks for the suggestion but I already try this and set timeout for 10 seconds still it won't work.

Comment: 2 things. 1) May be you missed here but your code might have proper semicolon(;) while using debugger; and $("#btnsubmit").click(); Now 2) is as you are assigning values to a lot of fields from your response data you should check if all those values are getting assigned before the .click() at the last line.

Comment: @KingshukDeb I have put semicolon to debugger and double check all the data and it's proper.
What I did is take form as diffrent html and put all the data coming in response and all working fine but with code it is not working.

Comment: Ok. If you put static data to all fields rather than assigning values.. does that work?

Comment: yes it worked successfully

Comment: Ok. So what it does when the click() function gets executed. My guess is you are sending all values to some controller or somewhere. May be when you are assigning values then it cant pass all values to that controller. The main thing is your assigning values are not working properly. Guess though. No offence.

Comment: @KingshukDeb It will redirected to payment gateway of CyberSource.

Comment: Ok. So now i can give you an idea. Before executing the click() function try to check length or values of all those hidden inputs. If there are 8 hidden fields then try to check all hidden fields have value assigned. If all values assigned fields count is 8 then only execute the click function else not. Basic idea is you need to wait until it assign values to all those fields.